# Function to find maximum of 3 variables isn't returning anything

Tags: python, function

What is my problem? I run `biggest(10,5,6)` but it returns nothing.

```
def biggest(a,y,z):
    Max=a
    if y>Max:
        Max=y
        if z>Max:
            Max=z
            return Max
```

Comment: You want to actually print the result of (biggest(10,5,6))  not just run it and do nothing with the result

Comment: Change your inputs on this to 10,5,20 you're indentation is incorrect for this to work... Also max(), but less important.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of indentation in your function. You've put the instruction `return Max` on the most inner level of your chain of `if`'s, so it returns result only if the maximum is `z` number. When the `a` or `y` is maximum it returns nothing. You can read more about python's attitude to indentation [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html).

```
def biggest(a, y, z):
    Max = a
    if y > Max:
        Max = y    
    if z > Max:
        Max = z
        if y > z:
            Max = y
    return Max
```

If you don't need to implement your own function, you can use built-in `max` function, as *Mingyu* [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18973601/885028).

Answer (score 30):

```
>>> max(2, 3, 5)
5
>>> help(max)
```

Help on built-in function max in module **builtin**:

```
max(...)
    max(iterable[, key=func]) -> value
    max(a, b, c, ...[, key=func]) -> value

    With a single iterable argument, return its largest item.
    With two or more arguments, return the largest argument.
(END)
```

Comment: @Mingyu is this correct usage for 3 lists?  `longest=(a,b,c,[,key=len])`?

Answer (score 0):

## I would suggest this...

```
def max_of_three(x,y,z):
    Max = x
    if y > Max:
        Max = y
    if z > Max:
        Max =z
    print Max
```

max_of_three(3,4,2)

prints 4

Answer (score 0):

**It would be better to use "max" function in python, the best thing about max  is, it is not restricted to 3 or 4 arguments.**

```
 """
    max(iterable, *[, default=obj, key=func]) -> value
    max(arg1, arg2, *args, *[, key=func]) -> value

    With a single iterable argument, return its biggest item. The
    default keyword-only argument specifies an object to return if
    the provided iterable is empty.
    With two or more arguments, return the largest argument.
    """

max_value = max(1, 2, 3)
print(max_value) # will return 3
```

Comment: How is this any different from Mingyu's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18973601/369450)?

Answer (score 0):

```
x = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
y = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
z = float(input("Enter the third number: "))
if x >= y and x >= z:
    maximum = x
elif y >= z and y >= x:
    maximum = y
else:
    maximum = z
print("The maximum no. b/w : ", x, ",", y, "and", z, "is", maximum)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  def findMax(a, b,c)

     return max(a, b,c)

  print(findMax(6, 9, -5)
```

Comment: How is this any different from Mingyu's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18973601/369450)?

Answer (score -2):

I'll just paste it here in case some new python student gets here.

```
def biggest (a, b, c):
    imax = a
    if (b > imax) and (b > c):
            imax = b
    elif (c > imax):
            imax = c
    return imax

#to test
print (biggest(5,6,7))
```

Answer (score -4):

```
if x>y>z:
    print ("max number is x : ",x)
if z>y : 
    print ("max number is z : ",z)
if y>z :
    print  ("max number is y : ",y)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Unfortunately, this answer is not correct.  Ignoring the formating (which someone was nice enough to fix in the edit queue), your answer A) Doesn't actually answer the user's question of why his code didn't work B) doesn't work for all inputs, specifically max(3,1,2) (or any other case where the first is the largest and the middle is the smallest), and also the edge case where some of the numbers are equal will sometimes print nothing in your case.